# Prolog comparing and returning true or false conditionally

Tags: prolog

I am new to the prolog and trying to solve some problems. I have two lists for example List1 and List2 respectively below:

```
List1: [[0.1, 0.6], [0.1, 0.5], [0.3, 0.5]]
List2: [0.2, 0.7, 0.4]
```

I need to check if nth element of the `List2` is between the range of the corresponding (nth) number pair in the `List1`. And if the number in `List2` is in the range, then check if the (n+1)th element of the `List2` satisfies the same condition. If a number does not satisfy the condition, then I need to return false. If all of the numbers in `List2` satisfies the condition, then I need to return true.

I came up with this idea, but it does not work and I could not find why.

```
bet(L, R, B) :-
    Factor1 is B-L,
    Factor2 is R-B,
    Factor1 > 0,
    Factor2 > 0.

comp_lims([], []).
comp_lims([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    member([Left|T], H1),
    member(Right, T),
    bet(Left, Right, H2) -> comp_lims(T1, T2); fail.
```

`bet` is actually a comparison predicate i wrote for the floating point numbers and it works fine when testing it like below:

```
?- bet(0.3, 0.7, 0.4).
true.

?- bet(0.3, 0.7, 0.8).
false.
```

But I cannot find what is wrong with the `comp_lims` predicate and I am stuck. A help will be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear from the problem description if the examples are correct. Where is `the (n+1)th element of the List2` in your example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
comp_lims([], []).
comp_lims([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    H1 = [Left, Right],
    ( bet(Left, Right, H2) -> comp_lims(T1, T2); fail ).
```

A Better version:

```
comp_lims([], []).
comp_lims([ [Left, Right] | T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    bet(Left, Right, H2), comp_lims(T1, T2).
```

1. Pattern matching need not just be `[Head|Tail]` form, you can just use `[A, B]` to match two element lists.
2. You can write `A -> B; fail` as just `A, B`(there is an implicit cut too, but you  can ignore it for now).

Also in `bet/3`, you can just do :

```
bet(L, R, B) :-
    B-L > 0,
    R-B > 0.
```

`>` implicitly evaluates both sides, so you do not need to use separate `is` for it.

Comment: Better to highlight the *scope* of if/then/else operators: `comp_lims([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :- H1 = [Left, Right], ( bet(Left, Right, H2) -> comp_lims(T1, T2) ; fail ).`, even if is not *necessary* for this particular code...